# how to create a wildfly bootable jar with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, wildfly

The documentation at https://docs.wildfly.org/bootablejar/ describes the usage of the maven plugin wildfly-jar-maven-plugin only. Is there a way to build something similar with gradle? What comes close is the hollow bootable jar: build it with maven and use it as a dependency in my gradle project to start my war.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Quarkus. But the application already exists and requires wildfly.